# Split column list into rows without duplicating data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the first column is a list, how can I iterate through the list and add a value to the relevant pre defined column:

```
workflow                cost      cam    gdp     ott    pdl
['cam', 'gdp', 'ott']   $2,346
['pdl', 'ott']          $1,200
```

should convert to:

```
workflow                cost      cam    gdp     ott    pdl
['cam', 'gdp', 'ott']   $2,346    782    782     782
['pdl', 'ott']          $1,200                   600    600
```

I can get the length of the list, but I can't work out how to iterate over the list in order to match it to a column heading. Basically the cost is simply split evenly between the number of processes in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative:

```py
df1 = (
    df.assign(cost=
        df["cost"].str.replace(r"\$|,", "", regex=True).astype("float")
        / df["workflow"].str.len()
    )
    .explode("workflow")
    .pivot(columns="workflow", values="cost")
)
df = pd.concat([df[["workflow", "cost"]], df1], axis=1)
```

Result for the sample:

```
          workflow    cost    cam    gdp    ott    pdl
0  [cam, gdp, ott]  $2,346  782.0  782.0  782.0    NaN
1       [pdl, ott]  $1,200    NaN    NaN  600.0  600.0
```

Comment: I had the same answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
for i in df.index:
    cost = float(df.loc[i,'cost'][1:].replace(',',''))
    cols = df.loc[i, 'workflow']
    df.loc[i,cols] = cost / len(cols)
```

Output:

```
          workflow    cost    cam    gdp    ott    pdl
0  [cam, gdp, ott]  $2,346  782.0  782.0  782.0    NaN
1       [pdl, ott]  $1,200    NaN    NaN  600.0  600.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(workflow=[['cam', 'gpd', 'ott'], ['pdl', 'ott']], 
                  cost=[2346, 1200]), dtype=object)

defaults = [782, 600]

for default_value, row in zip(defaults, df.iterrows()):
    index, row = row
    
    for col in row['workflow']:
        if col not in df:
            df[col] = [np.nan] * len(df)
        
        df.at[index, col] = default_value

print(df)
# yields
workflow  cost    cam    gpd    ott    pdl
0  [cam, gpd, ott]  2346  782.0  782.0  782.0    NaN
1       [pdl, ott]  1200    NaN    NaN  600.0  600.0
```

Answer (score 2):

With custom `df.apply`:

```
def fill_cols(x):
    cost = float(x['cost'][1:].replace(',', ''))
    x[x['workflow']] = cost / len(x['workflow'])
    return x

df = df.apply(fill_cols, axis=1)
```

---

```
          workflow    cost    cam    gdp    ott    pdl
0  [cam, gdp, ott]  $2,346  782.0  782.0  782.0    NaN
1       [pdl, ott]  $1,200    NaN    NaN  600.0  600.0
```

Comment: I really liked this one, it looked nice and tidy, I couldn't get it to work unfortunately, it

Comment: @iFunction, why could not you get it work?

Comment: Just tried it again and it has worked, there are all sorts of issues with the data unfortunately, some strings have quotes some don't, so that is causing issues so there are some keys that end up wrapped in two sets of quotes giving a key error. I'm going to persevere with it, I like the simplicity of it. Timus answer just dealt with all the messy strings.

Comment: @iFunction, you can just replace the line for `cost` with the following: `cost = float(x['cost'].replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
df['workflow'].to_frame().join(
   pd.DataFrame.from_records(
      [(x, y, x1, y/len(x), z) for x, y, z in 
       zip(df['workflow'], df['cost'], df.index)
       for x1 in x],
      columns = df.columns.to_list() + ['aux1', 'aux2', 'id'])
   .pivot(index=['id', 'cost'], columns='aux1', values='aux2')
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()).drop('id', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
          workflow  cost    cam    gpd    ott    pdl
0  [cam, gpd, ott]  2346  782.0  782.0  782.0    NaN
1       [pdl, ott]  1200    NaN    NaN  600.0  600.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best of ways but you can try it :

```
splits = (
   df.iloc[:, :2].explode("workflow").set_index("workflow", append=True)
     .assign(cost= lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x["cost"].replace(r"\$|,", "", regex=True)))
     .T.groupby(level=0, axis=1, group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g/len(*g.to_numpy()))
     .stack(0).reset_index(drop=True)
)

out = df.iloc[:, :2].join(splits)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

          workflow    cost    cam    gdp    ott    pdl
0  [cam, gdp, ott]  $2,346 782.00 782.00 782.00    NaN
1       [pdl, ott]  $1,200    NaN    NaN 600.00 600.00
```